# Multiple warning and errors using Git with Flutter in Android Studio

Tags: android, git, flutter, android-studio, android-manifest

Whenever I enable Git in any Flutter Project in Android Studio it gives me the following warning when I try to commit:

```
9 files contain problems.
18 errors and 12 warnings found.
Would you like to review them?
```

Is this supposed to happen? Because it also happens on a fresh standard Flutter App without any modifications. This is what it shows when clicked to review.

````
C:\Users\me\AndroidStudioProjects\flutter_app\android\app\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml
  Warning:(1, 2) Should set `android:versionCode` to specify the application version
  Warning:(1, 2) Should set `android:versionName` to specify the application version
  Warning:(5, 9) Unknown attribute android:icon
  Warning:(8, 13) Unknown attribute android:launchMode
  Warning:(9, 13) Unknown attribute android:theme
  Warning:(10, 13) Unknown attribute android:configChanges
  Warning:(11, 13) Unknown attribute android:hardwareAccelerated
  Warning:(11, 13) Attribute `hardwareAccelerated` is only used in API level 11 and higher (current min is 1)
  Warning:(12, 13) Unknown attribute android:windowSoftInputMode
  Warning:(12, 13) Attribute `windowSoftInputMode` is only used in API level 3 and higher (current min is 1)
  Error:(19, 33) Cannot resolve symbol '@style/NormalTheme'
  Error:(28, 33) Cannot resolve symbol '@drawable/launch_background'
C:\Users\me\AndroidStudioProjects\flutter_app\android\app\build.gradle
  Error:(1, 27) Cannot resolve symbol 'Properties'
  Error:(11, 15) Cannot resolve symbol 'GradleException'
C:\Users\me\AndroidStudioProjects\flutter_app\android\settings.gradle
  Error:(3, 31) Cannot resolve symbol 'File'
  Error:(4, 22) Cannot resolve symbol 'Properties'
C:\Users\me\AndroidStudioProjects\flutter_app\android\app\src\main\kotlin\com\heitorfranca\flutter_app\MainActivity.kt
  Error:(3, 19) Unresolved reference: embedding
  Error:(5, 21) Unresolved reference: FlutterActivity
C:\Users\me\AndroidStudioProjects\flutter_app\android\build.gradle
C:\Users\me\AndroidStudioProjects\flutter_app\android\app\src\main\res\drawable\launch_background.xml
  Error:(4, 29) Cannot resolve symbol '@android:color/white'
C:\Users\me\AndroidStudioProjects\flutter_app\android\app\src\main\res\drawable-v21\launch_background.xml
  Error:(4, 29) Cannot resolve symbol '?android:colorBackground'
C:\Users\me\AndroidStudioProjects\flutter_app\android\app\src\main\res\values-night\styles.xml
  Error:(4, 39) Cannot resolve symbol '@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar'
  Error:(7, 21) Cannot resolve symbol 'android:windowBackground'
  Error:(15, 39) Cannot resolve symbol '@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar'
  Error:(16, 21) Cannot resolve symbol 'android:windowBackground'
C:\Users\me\AndroidStudioProjects\flutter_app\android\app\src\main\res\values\styles.xml
  Error:(4, 39) Cannot resolve symbol '@android:style/Theme.Light.NoTitleBar'
  Error:(7, 21) Cannot resolve symbol 'android:windowBackground'
  Error:(15, 39) Cannot resolve symbol '@android:style/Theme.Light.NoTitleBar'
  Error:(16, 21) Cannot resolve symbol 'android:windowBackground'```
````